# Pages Module Randomly Reassigns Template

Tags: pages

I have some odd behavior with a site. I using the Pages Module and I have a template assigned correctly for entering new pages.

Every so often though, I'll go to the page on the front end and see the page does not look right. So I go to edit and I see the Pages Module has reassigned this page to another template. So I change it back... come back a few days later and it's changed again.

This behavior seems to happen on its own, not necessarily after editing anything or even visiting the site. I'm the only one editing.

Anyone had a similar issue?

Alternatively, anyone have an better solution to organizing without relying on Structure/Pages/Categories. The fact that the Pages Module does not work on the front-end via Channel Forms makes for client page creation impossible.

I am using EE 2.7.3